# (Application.Errors.invalidResponse) Cant fix invalidResponse error

Tags: ios, swift

I don't get it why its showing invalidResponse as error when I think I did it all right the Token is correct the api URL is correct and tested on Postman, but when debugging its showing error at invalidResponse or invalidData after the response error, I haven't yet tried to fill TableView with the incoming api data fields because I want to try first if its coming before proceeding :( :)

```
class APICaller {

static let shared = APICaller()
private let baseURL = "http://000.000.000.000:3030/api/"

private init() {}

func getVehicles(for id: String, completed: @escaping (Result<[Vehicles],OnTraErrors>) -> Void ){
    let endpoint = baseURL + "GetVehicles?UserIdentificationValue=\(id)"
    
    
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        completed(.failure(.invalidURL))
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 120)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"

    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "authorizetoken": "Bearer NjQzODM2N0NDNDM4NDhCNDk3RkU0NjA0QUY0NjVFS3GE=",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                ]
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        if let _ = error {
            completed(.failure(.unableToComplete))
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

            let vehicles = try decoder.decode([Vehicles].self, from: data)
            completed(.success(vehicles))
            
        } catch {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Unrelated but: iIf that's your personal Bearer, you might want to remove it from the question... Unrelated but in `catch { completed(.failure(.invalidData)) }`, please print `error`. If the parsing fails it will tell you why!. If I understood correctly, you get `completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))`, either response is not a `HTTPURLResponse`, or its `statusCode` is not 200. Might want to print the status code to check which one it is in reality...

Comment: @Larme Both status code and HTTPURLResponse are good and just checked but still its not showing the data, and yes the bearer token changes but for this test is valid just to try if its receiving, Do you have any other suggestions please?

Comment: It's unclear. What's called: `completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))`? Or `completed(.failure(.invalidData))`? Which one, there are plenty of them. Also did you print error in the `catch` as I suggested (and I strongly recommend to do it)?

Comment: completed(.failure(.invalidResponse)) is called and I did print error its not showing anything catch {
                print(error)
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))

Comment: What's the response status code then? Could you print response?